# Django 3.2: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working with Django 3.2, and have come across a problem that seems to have answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360477/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attname-django) and [here also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67628299/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attname), and I have tried the solutions offered in the accepted answers, but have not been able to resolve the issue I am having (error message in subject title).

Here is what my models look like:

```
#### models.py
class ActionableModel:

    def __init__(self, child_object):
        self.child = child_object

        # FIX: This might be an expensive operation ... need to investigate
        if isinstance(child_object, django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()):
            self.owner = child_object
            self.actionable_object = child_object
        else:
            self.owner = child_object.get_owner()
            self.actionable_object = child_object.get_actionable_object()

        self.owner_id = self.owner.id
        
        self.ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.actionable_object)
        self.object_id = self.actionable_object.id

    # ...


class Prey(models.Model):
    # ... fields
    pass


class Predator(models.Model, ActionableModel):
    catches = GenericRelation(Prey)
    catch_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)
    last_catch = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
     

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ActionableModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)  


    # ...
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


# Classes used for testing - naming similar to [mommy](https://model-mommy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html)
class Daddy():
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ActionableModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)      





class Foo(Daddy, Predator):
    # ...
    pass
```

In the shell, I type the following:

```
from myapp.models import Foo
admin = django.contrib.auth.get_user_model().objects.all().first()
foo = Foo.objects.create(child_object=admin)
```

Here is the stack trace of the error that results in the subject title:

```
Foo.objects.create(child_object=admin)                                                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                            
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                       
  File "/path/to/myapp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method  
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                
  File "/path/to/myapp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/path/to/myapp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 726, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/path/to/myapp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 763, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/path/to/myapp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 822, in _save_table
    pk_val = self._get_pk_val(meta) 
  File "/path/to/myapp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 575, in _get_pk_val
    return getattr(self, meta.pk.attname)
  File "/path/to/myapp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query_utils.py", line 148, in __get__
    val = self._check_parent_chain(instance)
  File "/path/to/myapp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query_utils.py", line 164, in _check_parent_chain
    return getattr(instance, link_field.attname)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'
```

What is causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: I assume it's because `Foo` inherits from `Model`, but you've defined your own `__init__()` method, so `Model.__init__()` is never called, which presumably is where `attname` would have been defined.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you inherit from a class but you don't call that class' `__init__` method, you're asking for trouble.

Comment: Why do you need to do all of those things specifically in the `__init__` method, is the `save` method not an option? The model class can generally be instantiated without passing any actual value to it.

Comment: You said you've tried the accepted solutions in the linked duplicate questions, but you haven't seemed to try the accepted answer to the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360477/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attname-django) you linked by calling the super class's `__init__` method?

Comment: have you checked what `admin` actually is after assignment? Is that a `None` value?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have models that derive from `ActionableModel` -  e.g. Run, Jump, Laugh etc. to create a kind of `Mixin`. Other models (for e.g. User) can then implement these "Mixins" - so at the time an object (say a User) is being instantiated, I need it's Mixins (Eat, Jump, Sleep etc.) to have a reference to user. In a way, this is kind-of dependency injection by the backdoor.  I want to pass the child object (User) to the parent class (Eat, Jump, Sleep etc.) during initialisation, so that the parent classes (Eat, ...) always have a reference to the child class.

Comment: If I map your above comment to the code you have shared you mean to say when you instantiate `Foo` at that time `Predator` should get a reference to `Foo`? But isn't `Predator` _abstract_? In that case why does there need to be a reference?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat You asked to questions **Q1:**  when you instantiate Foo at that time Predator should get a reference to Foo?  **A1:** Yes.  **Q2:** But isn't Predator abstract? In that case why does there need to be a reference? **A2:** Yes, Predator is abstract (though making it concrete is not a deal breaker). I made it abstract, so that each object that derived from it will have it's data in a separate table (for reasons I won't go into here). The reference is needed, because `Predator` interface has methods that invoke methods on the child class (poor man's callback if you like).

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the [`__init__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/08e6073f878264a0c091da0d3db456820252ef6c/django/db/models/base.py#L406) method from the django `Model` class never gets called. This is because an `__init__` method is defined in your derived class, but the `super()` method is not called explicitly.

Two things are needed:

- Setting up a chain of `super` calls.
- Ensuring the [method resolution order](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order) allows the chain of `super` to reach the `Model.__init__` method.

Applying these points to the source code provided:

```
class ActionableModel:

    def __init__(self, child_object, *args, **kwargs):
        # need to call super here
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.child = child_object
        ...


class Prey(models.Model):
    pass


class Predator(ActionableModel, models.Model):
    catches = GenericRelation(Prey)
    ...    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  


class Daddy:        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)      


class Foo(Daddy, Predator):
    pass
```

Comment: How would you call create an instance of `Foo` (and pass a `parent_object` variable to the parent `Predator` class - which also passes the `parent_object` variable to the `ActionableModel` class)?

Comment: Why did you decide to change the derivation order? I remember reading somewhere (can't remember where) - that when using multiple inheritance in Django, it's always best to derive from `models.Model` first. Do you have a canonical reference that supports your chosen derived order?

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect what I think you want to do. Given a `parent_object` instance, you would do `foo = Foo(parent_object)` to get a "local" object. To push to db, you will have to then call the `foo.save()` method assuming the other fields you need to satisfy the db constraints are correctly assigned.

Comment: I went back to source code and saw that `models.Model.__init__` actually calls its super method. This means that you could derive from `models.Model` first. However, given that the `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` call is the first thing to be executed in `ActionableModel`, `models.Model` initialization will be done before the rest of `ActionableModel.__init__` is run. In other words, given how the code above is written, interchanging derivation order should yield the same result.